# I'm getting this error.expected an indented block.What should I do?

Tags: python

```
def shut_down(s):

if s == "yes":
    return "Shutting down"
elif s == "no":
    return "Shutdown aborted"
else:
    return "Sorry"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could try putting an indented block, as it says it is expecting an indented block.

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s == "yes":
        return "Shutting down"
    elif s == "no":
        return "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        return "Sorry"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.now It's running true.but What's wrong in my code?Did I put a lot of spaces?in fact I don't understand why does my code get error.

Comment: In Python, everything depends on the indentation. [Here is a small tutorial.](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php) Since the code you posted was not indented at all, it was incomprehensible.